# receiving the error response with AFHTTPClient calls

Tags: json, afnetworking

I'm implementing AFHTTPClient as a singleton class, as recommended in the docs, and calling that with JSON data in a post, and receiving JSON data in return:

```
[[BMNetworkCalls sharedInstance] postPath:theURL parameters:theDict success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"my return is: %@", [responseObject valueForKeyPath:@"Result"]);

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {            
    NSLog(@"error in network call: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}];
```

All fine and good, but if I receive an error, ("error in HTTPRequestOperation: Expected status code in (200-299), got 400"), I actually *want* to read the responseObject here as well (this is the way the API I am using tells me what class of error I caused).

I could do that using AFJSONRequestOperation:

```
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    NSLog(@"my return is: %@", [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"Result"]);

} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
    NSLog(@"exception code: %@", [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"ExceptionCode"]);
    NSLog(@"exception message: %@", [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"ExceptionMessage"]);
}];
[operation start];
```

How can I (and can I?) do it using AFHTTPClient?

Comment: You should write a custom method in BMNetworkCalls for each API call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `operation` variable has everything that you need:

```
[[BMNetworkCalls sharedInstance] postPath:theURL parameters:theDict success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
  // ...
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    if ([operation isKindOfClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]]) {
      id JSON = [(AFJSONRequestOperation *)operation responseJSON];
      NSLog(@"JSON: %@", JSON)
    }
}];
```

Comment: NOW you tell me.. (grin). Note that my answer below works, even if unnecessary.

Answer (score -1):

All credit goes to @phix23, who pointed me in the correct direction!

Here is the custom method I wrote in my subclassed AFHTTPClient that allows me to see the JSON response after receiving a 400 error:

```
- (void) myPostPath:(NSString *)path
        parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
           success:(void (^)(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON))success 
           failure:(void (^)(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON))failure
{
    NSURLRequest *request = [self requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:path parameters:parameters];   
    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:success failure:failure];
    [self enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
}
```

I call it by:

```
[[BMNetworkCalls sharedInstance] myPostPath:theURL parameters:theDict success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"my return is: %@", [responseObject valueForKeyPath:@"Result"]);

} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {          
    NSLog(@"exception code: %@", [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"ExceptionCode"]);
}];
```

Comment: This is unnecessary. You can access the responseJSON property of operation variable that is normally passed in the failure callback block.